# jquery giving me undefined value for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html

```
$('#div1').append("<table id='" + response + "_" + "fawad" + "' width='100%' style='border-bottom-style:inset; border-bottom-width:thin'><tr><td width='595px'>Company Name: </td><td id='" + response + "_" + "fawad" + "_cname'>" + txtName.value + "</td></tr><tr><td>From Date </td><td id='" + response + "_" + "fawad" + "_fromd'>" + txtFrom.value + "</td></tr><tr><td>To Date </td><td id='" + response + "_" + "fawad" + "_tdate'>" + txtTo.value + "</td></tr><tr><td>Position </td><td id='" + response + "_" + "fawad" + "_position'>" + txtPosition.value + "</td><td><linkbutton  onclick='passp(this)'>edit</linkbutton></td></tr></table>");
```

I using Jquery to access the element value like this

```
$("#txtName").val($($(elem).closest('table').attr('id')+"_cname").val());
```

it's giving me undefined in txtName value.

txtName is a textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
```

Please help

Comment: That's a mighty long line of code there. Methinks a 600+ char line of code might not be the best approach. What's undefined when? What's `txtName`? What?

Comment: Do you intend to have `+ "fawad" +` in quotes, or is `fawad` a variable? You're doing an unnecessary concatenation there. If it's meant to be a string, then you can make it part of the strings surrounding it: `response + "_fawad' width='100%'..."`

Comment: please provide more information or provide jsfiddle that would be best

Comment: @cookiemonster fawad is a string

Comment: Then I'd suggest making it part of the previous and next string. The concatenation there make is unnecessary and begs the question.

Comment: Plus, we don't know what `elem` is, and it would be a lot easier if you posted the HTML rendered instead of the jQuery used to create it.

Comment: Is `elem` coming from here? `<linkbutton  onclick='passp(this)'>edit</linkbutton>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#txtName").val($('#' + $(elem).closest('table').attr('id')+"_cname").text());
```

Should solve it.

You were trying to get an element by id without `"#"`, and trying to get `val()` of a `td`.

I put the `#` and changed `val()` to `text()`.

Comment: I gave +1, but you shouldn't give an explanation only in response to a down vote. It's a good idea to do it up front so that the OP and others can clearly see what you changed.

Comment: The hash is not concatenated with "elem", but with $(elem).closest('table').attr('id')+"_cname", wich is a string. Original code has: "<td id='" + response + "_" + "fawad" + "_cname'>"

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the value (`val()`) which is only applicable for input elements. Change to `html()` -

```
$("#txtName").val($($(elem).closest('table').attr('id')+"_cname").html());
```

If `#txtName` is not an input you will need to change the method there too. plus it appears that there are some typos. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2axfN/

```
$("#txtName").html( $('td:first').closest('table').attr('id') );
```

Updated with an input field: http://jsfiddle.net/2axfN/1/

```
$('input[name="foo"]').val( $('td:first').closest('table').attr('id') );
```

One more update to add '_cname' to the end of the value:

```
$("#txtName").html( $('linkbutton').closest('table').attr('id') + "_cname");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2axfN/3/